# AII assumption- hmftest

Tags: r

I am trying to run a hmftest in mlogit package. There is an example online, but I really do not understand it.

Say I have 3 categories: 1,2,3, and two continuous variables:A, B. I really just need to run a Hausman-McFadden test to see if the independence assumption holds in my multinomial logistic regression.
I don't understand the example mainly because I don't know the nature of variables in this example.

```
## from Greene's Econometric Analysis p. 731

data("TravelMode",package="AER")
TravelMode <- mlogit.data(TravelMode,choice="choice",shape="long",
alt.var="mode",chid.var="individual")

## Create a variable of income only for the air mode
TravelMode$avinc <- with(TravelMode,(mode=='air')*income)

## Estimate the model on all alternatives, with car as the base level
## like in Greene's book.
#x <- mlogit(choice~wait+gcost+avinc,TravelMode,reflevel="car")
x <- mlogit(choice~wait+gcost+avinc,TravelMode)

## Estimate the same model for ground modes only (the variable avinc
## must be dropped because it is 0 for every observation
g <- mlogit(choice~wait+gcost,TravelMode,reflevel="car",
alt.subset=c("car","bus","train"))

## Compute the test
hmftest(x,g)
```

Can anyone who understands the above example provide some help? Thank you very much,

Comment: Are yous asking about the meaning/interpretation of the test? That kind of question might be better off on stats.stackexchange.com, but you might also need to be more specific about where your confusion lies (not understanding the output?).

Comment: Thanks. I am asking how to write the code by following this example.